# How can I specialise instances of objects when I don't have access to the instantiation code?

Tags: python

Let's assume I am using a library which gives me instances of classes defined in that library when calling its functions:

```
>>> from library import find_objects
>>> result = find_objects("name = any")
[SomeObject(name="foo"), SomeObject(name="bar")]
```

Let's further assume that I want to attach new attributes to these instances. For example a classifier to avoid running this code every time I want to classify the instance:

```
>>> from library import find_objects
>>> result = find_objects("name = any")
>>> for row in result:
...     row.item_class= my_classifier(row)
```

Note that this is contrived but illustrates the problem: **I now have instances of the class `SomeObject` but the attribute `item_class` is not defined in that class and trips up the type-checker.**

So when I now write:

```
print(result[0].item_class)
```

I get a typing error. It also trips up auto-completion in editors as the editor does not know that this attribute exists.

And, not to mention that this way of implementing this is quite ugly and hacky.

One thing I could do is create a subclass of `SomeObject`:

```
class ExtendedObject(SomeObject):

    item_class = None

    def classify(self):
        cls = do_something_with(self)
        self.item_class = cls
```

This now makes everything explicit, I get a chance to properly document the new attributes and give it proper type-hints. Everything is clean. However, as mentioned before, the actual instances are created inside *library* and I don't have control over the instantiation.

Side note: I ran into this issue in `flask` for the `Response` class. I noticed that `flask` actually offers a way to customise the instantiation using `Flask.response_class`. But I am still interested how this could be achieved in libraries that don't offer this injection seam.

One thing I could do is write a wrapper that does something like this:

```
class WrappedObject(SomeObject):

    item_class = None
    wrapped = None

    @staticmethod
    def from_original(wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        self.item_class = do_something_with(wrapped)

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.wrapped, key)
```

But this seems rather hacky and will not work in other programming languages.

Or try to copy the data:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class CopiedObject(SomeObject):

    item_class = None

    @staticmethod
    def from_original(wrapped):
        for key, value in vars(wrapped):
            setattr(self, key, deepcopy(value))
        self.item_class = do_something_with(wrapped)
```

but this feels equally hacky, and is risky when the objects sue properties and/or descriptors.

Are there any known "clean" patterns for something like this?

Comment: To be honest, all of this seems like a lot of effort to go to in order to satisfy the (totally optional) type checker.

Comment: It is not *only* to satisfy the type-checker but it is a positive side-effect. I have been faced with this more than once in my career in different languages and really wonder if there is a pattern that makes this cleaner or easier.

Comment: Fair enough. I doubt you'll get a cleaner solution though. The other approach would be to monkey-patch the class itself, which is acceptable in Ruby for example but would be seen as very hacky in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a variant of your `WrappedObject` approach, with the following adjustments:

- I would not extend `SomeObject`: this is a case where composition feels more appropriate than inheritance
- With that in mind, `from_original` is unnecessary: you can have a proper `__init__` method
- `item_class` should be an instance variable and not a class variable. It should be initialized in your `WrappedObject` class constructor
- Think twice before implementing `__getattribute__` and forwarding everything to the wrapped object. If you need only a few method and attributes of the original `SomeObject` class, it might be better to implement them explicitly as methods and properties

```py
class WrappedObject:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        self.item_class = do_something_with(wrapped)

    def a_method(self):
        return self.wrapped.a_method()

    @property
    def a_property(self):
        return self.wrapped.a_property
```

Comment: What is your main concern about using `__getattribute__`?

Comment: I don't have a problem with it,, but it depends of your exact intent: do you really want to work with `SomeObject` instances, with their original behaviour, and a few additional method / attributes? Or do you want to work with something more specific to your use case? For the former, `__getattribute__` is probably fine, but will feel like magic. For the latter, I would go the explicit way.